# Processing dataframe using multiprocess/multithread

Tags: python, dataframe, multithreading, multiprocessing, text-processing

I have a large pandas dataframe with one column "sentence" that contains text (each entry might be around 100 words and there are around 200000 entries). I would like to make a dictionary with all the text appearing in this column where the keys are the words and the values are the absolute frequencies. My attempt was to write the following function:

```
def word_counter(text):
    text_as_list = text.split()
    d = {w: text_as_list.count(w) for w in set(text_as_list)}
    return dict(sorted(d.items()))
```

So I just have to call the function with the right argument:

```
word_counter(' '.join(df["sentence"]))
```

Execution time seems endless, I waited for 20 minutes and it was still running. I think my solution is not bad (I have not made a time complexity analysis but it looks very "pythonic" to me so I guess is not a bad solution). I was wondering if there is a better way to do this or maybe if this specific task could be one of those cases appropriate for multiprocessing/multithreading? Which one would be more appropriate in this situation? Why?

I would appreciate a solution based on ProcessPoolExecutor/ThreadPoolExecutor since is much easier for me to understand.

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind regards.

Comment: This is a function applied to each value in the column? And you want a new column of dicts, one per row in the original df? Sorting is important?

Comment: Assuming your dataframe is `df`, maybe you want `from collections import Counter` followed by `df["sentence"].str.split().apply(Counter)`.

Comment: @tdelaney the answer is no. I do not want a dictionary for each entry, I want a single dictionary from the whole text in every entry, that's why I call the function with the argument `' '.join(df["sentence"])`. Yes sorting is important, should be sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collections.Counter` should be faster than your implementation and `itertools.chain.from_iterable` can help you avoid creating a single long string and split list in favor of small iterable chunks. Put it all together and you get

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import collections
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"sentence":["three", "two three", "one two three"]})
>>> counts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in df["sentence"]))
>>> counts = dict(sorted(counts.items()))
>>> counts
{'one': 1, 'three': 3, 'two': 2}
```

Comment: Yes this actually works quite nicely, is fast and elegant. I am not very familiar with either collections or itertools though will have to read the doc to fully understand whats going on. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Counter is implemented in C and chain means you don't have to allocate a lot of memory. Glad it worked.